# Sorting by a variable range?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range

I am fairly new to vba and have been trying to create a dynamic range based off of the 'usedrange' function. I seem to be having two different problems at the moment that I cannot find answers for:

1. I cannot figure out how to set my variable range (gimrange) equal to the entire worksheet (I have been using usedrange but am open to other suggestions).
2. Once gimrange is a viable variable range, how do I reference it within a sort function? I had this problem even before I started using usedrange with really any variable range.

Can anyone help a guy out? Here is my code as is:

```
Worksheets("GIM").UsedRange

Worksheets("GIM").UsedRange.Select

Dim gimrange As Range

Set gimrange = "worksheets(""GIM"").UsedRange"


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GIM").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GIM").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=gimrange, _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("GIM").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=gimrange, _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: Try `Set gimrange = Worksheets("GIM").UsedRange` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort your complete Worksheet by column A and B, code could look like this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("sheet2")

With ws.Sort

    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    .SetRange ws.UsedRange
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

It's not a must to use a worksheet variable but I prefer to do so because it's much easier to adapt the code